# GooglePlus Login fail :The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)

Tags: ios, xcode, google-play-services, prime31

I'm using Google Play Game Services Prime31 Unity Plugin for my Unity - IOS project. After I import Unity package and build for IOS, I'm not getting build error on Xcode. However, at runtime, when I try Google+ sign in I am getting this error:

**"GooglePlus Login fail :The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)"**

When i press sign in button, choice of google account screen is displayed but after i choose an account, it returns without signing in(following cancel-OK screen is not displayed) and gives the error that I've quoted.

At Unity I've used init method where I passed clientID(which is surely called before auth method) and I set **Info.plist additions** properly. When I press sign in button **PlayGameServices.authenticate()** is called. Should I add some other method or sth at Xcode? How can I solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

u test ur app in iOS 8?? I using another google play service plugin and also getting this error when running in iOS 8. But my app is work well in iOS 7.

Comment: After I add my account as test account to settings problem solved.

** When i was dealing with the problem, i already added my account as test account under Play.google/Game Services/MyProject/Testing. However, it was not added to general settings. After adding my account as test account under settings (gear icon in play.google) the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of issue :

**Cause 1:** May be bundle id of google console and your application is not matching .(application bundle id and google console bundle id should be same).

Solution : Steps 
**a:** GoTo google console and login with your application google account .

***for finding key*** :: **open google console > select your project > API & Auth > Credential**

**b:** change bundle id and regenerate key .

**c:** replace previous key with your new generated key .
**[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];**

**Cause 2:** May be key is not matching with you google console key .

Solution: Just replace your application key with google console key .
**[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];**

Note: Make sure your application bundle id and google console bundle id is same .